# Similar Triangles--Find the measurement of the unknown side

Tags: geometry, triangles

This is a question I know I got wrong on a final exam in a very easy class for teaching elementary geometry/prep for Praxis II. I actually received a 99% average in the entire course because of the single point taken off of the final. I just want to know how to go about solving this. I feel like I overthought the question. It was a multiple choice question and none of the answers seemed to make any sense to me. The question was to find the measurement of line segment CD.
[image]
Don't quote me on this, but I believe the choices were:

A.) 5 cm 
B.) 16 cm 
C.) 19 cm 
D.) 25 cm

Either way. We don't really need the choices to answer the question. I just want to know how to go about solving this. I know it has to do with similar triangles and creating a super easy proportion, but I tried every method I could think of. None of my answers were close to what the multiple choice answers were. So, I obviously did something wrong.

In case it's hard to see, AD=18cm AB= 7cm BC= 6cm. Triangle is not drawn to scale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that the sum of any two sides of a triangle is greater than the third side. That will be enough to eliminate $3$ of the given choices.

For example, $CD$ cannot be $5$, since $7+(6+5)$ is not greater than $18$.

Comment: Ah, that slipped my mind. That specific property wasn't taught to us in class, but I do recall it now. I can see that the answer would be "B." Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Comment: The specific property is sometimes called the *triangle inequality*. There is no other way. We are told that the triangle is not necessarily drawn to scale, so all we know about $CD$ is that the triangle must be drawable. The only reason $CD$ is $16$ is that the other alternatives are impossible, and we are supposed to assume that one of the answers is right. If this wasn't a multiple choice question, $CD$ could be many things other than $16$.